# using selectionStart on programmatically-created inputs

Tags: javascript, html, selection-api

Is it possible to set and get `.selectionStart` and `.selectionEnd` on a `<textarea>` that I create programmatically?

### Example

```
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
input.selectionStart; // 0 - just to confirm the property exists
input.selectionStart = 2; // returns 2
input.selectionStart; // returns 0, it should be 2
```

The above works fine in the `textarea` actually exists in the HTML of the page, but not when done as above (in Chrome at least).

The reason I want to do this is because I am testing a directive in AngularJS that manipulates a `textarea` and as part of my test I want to specify the position of the caret.

If not possible, is there a reason? And is there an alternative to setting the caret in a unit test?

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628323/textarea-selectionstart-in-ie

Comment: you have to have something inside the text area to change the `selectionStart` property

Comment: @Gyandeep thanks but that wasn't the issue - see the accepted answer - that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn3tT/)

```
var input = document.createElement("textarea");

// Add the manually created element to the document body
document.body.appendChild(input);

// Just added to confirm visually
input.textContent = "Something clever here";
input.selectionStart = 2; // returns 2
input.selectionEnd = input.textLength - 2;
```